# How pass function with ref on a class to another class without using props? is it possible? (ReactNative)

Tags: javascript, react-native

For example , I have 2 classes named A and B. and then I instantiate ScrollView component on  class A then access reference of it using ref attribute. what I want to do is to call this.ref inside Class B. I just want to control scrollTo method inside class B.

my desired output is . when I trigger a button on class B, class A ScrollView will scroll

```
class A extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.scrollRef = React.createRef()
  }

  render(){
    return <ScrollView ref={this.scrollRef}/>
  }
}

class B extends Component{
  //use class A this.scrollRef
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```js
class A extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.scrollRef = React.createRef()
  }

  onScrollToRequested = value => {
    this.scrollRef.scrollTo(value)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <ScrollView ref={this.scrollRef} />
        <B onScrollToRequest={this.onScrollToRequested} />
      </View>
    )

  }
}

class B extends Component{
  //use class A this.scrollRef
  onScrollToRequested = () => {
     this.props.onScrollToRequest(...);
  }
}
```